# Push a list of number into an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, push

I have an array

```
 var topics = [];
```

I have a list of numbers 1-10

```
var obj = {one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4, five:5, six:6, seven:7, eight:8, nine:9, ten:10};
```

I just want to push the number into the array but not sure what to call it in the push function?:

```
$.each(obj, function(i, val) { 
    topics.push({
        count: val
    });
    console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: ***that looks right to me...   http://jsfiddle.net/WbASp/***

Comment: What is `count`? Can you show an example of what you want the final `topics` array to look like? (I've given an answer with my best guess, but I can think of several other interpretations of your question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is for the final array to look like this:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

Then within your existing function you just need to say:

```
topics.push(val);
```

If your intention is for the final array to look like this:

```
[ "one", "two", "three", "four" /* etc */ ]
```

Then within your existing function you just need to say:

```
topics.push(i);
```

If your intention is for the final array to look like this:

```
[ { one : 1 }, { two : 2 }, { three : 3 } /* and so forth */ ]
```

Then you would do it like this:

```
$.each(obj, function(i, val) {
   var item = {};
   item[i] = val;
   topics.push(item);
   console.log(val);
});
```

You can't just say:

```
topics.push( { i : val } );
```

Because JS object literal syntax doesn't allow use of variables for the property names (keys) though it does allow variables for the property values, so `{ i : val }` creates an object with one property called "i".

In your code, if `count` is a variable you would use it like I showed above, i.e.,:

```
item[count] = val;
```

If "count" is the actual string that you want the property to be called then your code will work as is.

Answer (score 1):

```
var topics = []
var obj = {one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4, five:5, six:6, seven:7, eight:8, nine:9, ten:10};
```

Javascript way,

```
for(var i in obj){
topics.push(obj[i])
}
```

jQuery way,

```
$.each(obj,function(k,v){
topics.push(v)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.each(obj, function(i, val) { 

    topics.push(val); 

 });


   console.log(topics);
```